# Trigger button click

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to do something that I'm not sure it's possible.

At the moment, http://tvitni.brownfolder.com redirects you to another page.
What I want is, after the redirect, the third button (at the bottom) to be clicked automatically.

Is this possible to be done with PHP ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you change the code of the other page? (i.e. could you add some JavaScript there?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP cannot perform client-side actions such as clicking a button. You can use JavaScript to do this, but you need to be able to modify the resulting page to do this.

Comment: I was afraid of answer like this :)... Thanks anyway.